# Python получение первого элемента в списках

Tags: python

Имеется список списков
Как можно получить список только первых элементов внутренних списков без использования этой конструкции

```
main_list = [[], [], []]
def get_first_item_list():
    list = []
    for main in mail_list:
        list.append(main[0]
    return list
```

Точнее не список списков, а вроде список кортежей

```
[(1157, 'AMD FirePro 2270'),
 (1156, 'AMD FirePro 2270 1GB Edition'),
 (1155, 'AMD FirePro 2270 PCIe x1')]
```

Comment: Напишите входной список списков, `main_list`

Comment: @S.Nick ниже список кортежей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
main_list = [(1157, 'AMD FirePro 2270'),
 (1156, 'AMD FirePro 2270 1GB Edition'),
 (1155, 'AMD FirePro 2270 PCIe x1')]

[ i[0] for i in main_list]

[1157, 1156, 1155]
```